How to create a new instance of anonymous object inheriting an abstract?
I initially have this code when using this old library, the idea here is to support the scenario where multiple table tags exist in data then render multiple table span in TextView. To get onclick events it is using the newInstance() method.
htmlTxtV.setClickableTableSpan(ClickableTableSpanImpl(intentDomain))

inner class ClickableTableSpanImpl(private val intentDomain: WordPressPostDataDomain) :
        ClickableTableSpan() {

        override fun newInstance(): ClickableTableSpan {
            return ClickableTableSpanImpl(intentDomain)
        }

        override fun onClick(widget: View) {
            // Do task here
        }

    }

If I convert it to anonymous object
setClickableTableSpan(object : ClickableTableSpan() {

                    override fun newInstance(): ClickableTableSpan {
                        return this
                    }

                    override fun onClick(widget: View) {
                        // Do task here
                    }

                })

I only get single callback from the last span. Meaning the return this is not equivalent to return ClickableTableSpanImpl(). Is it possible to create new instance by just using anonymous object?

Please clarify "I only get single callback from the last span."

Why do you need it to be an object? The class-based impl seems to meet your needs.

@Josh to simplify the code, this question is to also learn more about possibilities in the language.

Your inner class-based approach is fine as it is. If you just want to "learn more about possibilities in the language", it is also possible to declare a local function like this:
fun main() {
    fun clickableTableSpan(): ClickableTableSpan = object: ClickableTableSpan {
        override fun newInstance(): ClickableTableSpan {
            return clickableTableSpan()
        }

        // ...
    }

    setClickableTableSpan(clickableTableSpan())
}

If you want to do this in a single expression, you can wrap the whole thing into an immediately-invoked lambda expression.
setClickableTableSpan({
        fun clickableTableSpan(): ClickableTableSpan = object: ClickableTableSpan {
            override fun newInstance(): ClickableTableSpan {
                return clickableTableSpan()
            }
        }
        clickableTableSpan()
    }())

But IMO, the inner class is way more readable.

Your second code sample is doing exactly what you are asking - creating an instance of an object which inherits from an abstract class.
It sounds like you want this object's newInstance() method to create more instances of subclasses that mimic the implementation of the original?
This isn't something that can be done with a single object instance. You are asking to create multiple instances of an abstract class's subclass with the same implementation. This is, by definition, the job of a child class (your first example.)
The first method you have shown seems to be the ideal solution.
